# why am i not able to use Response.Redirect two times in my codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

my codes are

```
if (k =="")
{
    Label1.Text = "User Name or Password wrong !";
}
else if (k == "user")
{

    Response.Redirect("admin_info.aspx",false);

}
else if (k == "admin")
{

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx",false);
}
```

When i use `k == "admin"` whether it's before use or after user it works, but `k == "user"` response.redirect not working.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer we arrived at yesterday, it would be great if you could accept it. I can add more detail if need be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be of authentication as I guess. 
I guess you are using form-authentication. If so then you have to first authenticate the user and then redirect to other page.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(k, false);
Response.Redirect("admin_info.aspx",false);
```

Comment: No i am not using form-authentication

Comment: then there may be a region that the page on which you are redirecting is itself redirecting you back to the first page

Answer (score 0):

Write k=string.empty when you will initialize your k.

Also change Response.Redirect("admin_info.aspx",True) in your redirection Code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that debugging appeared to show the `else if (k == "user")` check succeeding, the most likely explanation is that the redirect in question is actually working, but the `admin_info.aspx` page is also redirecting.